# Problems with my binary search and linear search

Tags: search, linear-search

I've tried using both binary search, and while loops and for loops in my searches and the same problem is occurring.

When my original program comes to this function call, the linear search function (displayContent) will always assign -1 to position, and after the function call the program breaks and exits.

I have tried to rearrange my program. Like I said, I tried for loops and while loops with both binary and linear search.

I am also using a structure data type of

```
struct info
{
    string name;
    double score[5];
    double avg;
};
```

Here is my function call

```
cout<<"Please enter the name of the person which you would like to search. ";
getline(cin, name);
cin.ignore();
displayContent(contestant, count, name);
```

Here is my function definition

```
void displayContent(info contest[], int quantity, string id)
{
int position=-1;
bool found=false;

for(int index=0;index<quantity && !found;index++)
{
    if(contest[index].name.compare(id)==0)
    {
        found=true;
        position=index;
    }
}
    if(position==-1)
    {
        cout<<"That person was not one of the contestants.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The scores for "<<contest[position].name<<" are \n     Contestant     Judge1  Judge2  Judge3  Judge4  Judge5  Average"
            <<"\n______________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
        cout<<right<<setw(15)<<fixed<<setprecision(1)    <<contest[position].name<<setw(10)<<contest[position].score[0]<<setw(8)<<contest[position].score[1]<<setw(8)<<contest[position].score[2]<<setw(8)<<contest[position].score[3]
        <<setw(8)<<contest[position].score[4]<<setw(8)<<contest[position].avg<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that `getline` does what you expect? Perhaps `name` contains a line ending character. To rule out problems with input you can try to assign a value to `name` you know exists in `contestant` before calling `displayContent`.

I haven't been able to spot any problems in your search algorithm.

Comment: ur answer has definitely helped me in finding that my error is not in my input or in my algorithm, but i had this function call embedded in a switch as well for other unsaid reasons, but the function works perfectly fine when i use it outside the switch, so i thank you. Btw would you know why this would occur when i use this function inside a switch?

Comment: `switch` statements can be confusing. If a `case` isn't terminated by a `break` the code "falls trough" to the next `case`. Also local variables are only scoped inside the `switch` block and not inside each `case` block. If you are able to use a debugger to single step through your code you should be able to determine the source of the problem. Otherwise you can try to insert extra debugging output to verify the value of interesting variables.